# How to move from directory to directory?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` function. After I get current directory path I need to move two directories up and to get the path of this derictory to the path variable.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "two directories down"?

Comment: Assuming you do actually mean 'down' and not 'up', and you have a single directory that is contained in the current folder you could check the contents of the current directory, and find the first folder - then move to this directory, and so on. Why you'd want to do this remains a mystery though!

Comment: You accepted an an answer regarding 'moving two directories up'. Please edit and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant moving up, not down:

```
var x = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var result = x.Parent.Parent;
```

You can now get all the data of that directory like:

```
var fullName = result.FullName;
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You mean two directories up? If you are moving up, use [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx). You cannot *arbitrarily* move down, you need to know where you are going.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method to return a different directory, you'll need to use the matching `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` method to change the working directory of the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx

If you're wanting to move down, you can use the `Directory.GetDirectories()` method to view all folders in the current path, and then use the `Directory.SetDirectory()` method to set it to one of those. Repeat once more to get "two directories down". Sans error handling (and presuming you want the first directory each time):

```
var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
directory = directories.First();
directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
directory = directories.First();
```

If you do actually mean **UP** rather than down, then as others have said, use the `Directory.GetParent()` method to get the parent of the current directory... twice.